# spring cloud gateway no redirect to other application

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a movies API which is exposed on port 9001 and I am trying to build a gateway API on port 9000 to redirect the requests to the movies API. Java 17, OS Win10

Here is code for movies API.

Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MoviesAPI {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MoviesAPI.class);

    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public MoviesAPI(MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Movie> getAll(){
        log.info("REST request to get all movies");
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Optional<Movie> saveMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
        log.info("REST request to save movie : {}", movie);
        movie.setLastUpdatedTime(Instant.now());
        return Optional.of(movieRepository.save(movie));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Movie> getMovieById(@PathVariable UUID id){
        log.info("REST request to get movie by id : {}", id);
        return movieRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteMovie(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        log.info("REST request to delete movie by id : {}", id);
        if (movieRepository.existsById(id)) {
            movieRepository.deleteById(id);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Movie with ID " + id + " not found");
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 9001
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: movies1
# swagger-ui custom path
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
```

Main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmartProxyJavocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmartProxyJavocApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And here is the code for gateway API.

Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gateway")
public class GatewayFallback {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayFallback.class);

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getAccount() {
        return "yes";
    }

}
```

application.yml :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: route1
          # where we send traffic
          uri: http://localhost:9001/api/movies
          predicates:
            - Path=/gateway/all
server:
  port: 9000
```

Main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have tried several values for Path like : `/gateway/all/**, /gateway/**`, changing the server port for gateway (8080). The code seems good according to the tutorials and articles I've read but still I can't figure out what is the problem.

Comment: What are APIs you already tried from Postman (or any client)? Please provide an example here.

Comment: Remove the gateway controller. The uri only is for the host and port. You need to use a filter such as setpath, or rewrite path

Comment: thanks a lot @spencergibb, I removed the gateway controller and searched more about SetPath and RewritePath and finally it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route1
      # where we send traffic
        uri: http://localhost:9001/api/movies
        predicates:
        - Path=/movies/**
        filters:
          - RewritePath=/movies/(?<segment>.*),/api/movies/$\{segment}
```

This is the final configuration that has worked.
Here is the example which I found and adapted to my case from Baeldung [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-url-rewriting). Thanks a lot to [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) for directions with SetPath and RewritePath.

I needed all from /movies/** , to go to /api/movies/** in the other app, and now it works.

Comment: In your particular case you could also use the prefix path filter